# How do I replicate this background image effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

Using this example:  http://www.meridianapps.com/

I like the way the background image expands and enlarges when you open the browser wider.  But it also has a minimum width if you try to minimize the browser.

I would like to replicate this.  Can someone point me to a plugin or code that I can use to insert something like this into my site?

Answer (score 1):

They are using `background-size: cover;` which scales the background image to be

> ... as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are
>   greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the
>   background positioning area.

[Here are the docs from Mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

This attribute should work in any browser except IE8 according to [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts).

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea about this CSS attribute

Answer (score 1):

**Awesome, Easy, Progressive CSS3 Way**
We can do this purely through CSS thanks to the background-size property now in CSS3. We'll use the html element (better than body as it's always at least the height of the browser window). We set a fixed and centered background on it, then adjust it's size using background-size set to the cover keyword.
try this

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)